# How to integrate reciprocal of square root?

Tags: calculus

How do you integrate the following?

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x+x^2}}
$$

Just a hint should suffice..

thanks!

Comment: [For any quadratic polynomial inside a square root, inside a rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

Comment: The only tricky thing is that the square root is $|1-x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$1-2x+x^2=(1-x)^2~~~~$$